# How to find out if bottle server has successful started up?

Tags: python, bottle

It is a typical, minimal example of a `bottle` web server

```
from bottle import route, run, template

@route('/hello/<name>')
def index(name):
    return template('<b>Hello {{name}}</b>!', name=name)

run(host='localhost', port=8080)
```

How can I find out if `run` has successfully started up an instance of a `bottle` server and the server is ready to receive incoming http call?

Comment: I suppose you can connect with `httplib` (or `http.client` if you have python3,) but I have never needed it.

Answer (score 1):

Using a web browser, try to browse to `http://localhost:8080/hello/Anthony`.  If you are on linux, try `wget http://localhost:8080/hello/Anthony`.